# Solr undefined field active

Tags: spring, spring-boot, solr

I am getting this undefined field 'active' error, but active field exist in schema. This was working previously without any errors, suddenly this error appears:
My Solr Document:

```
 @Data
   @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class SDocument {

    @Id
    @Field
    private String indexId;
    @Field("code")
    private String code;
    @Field("name")
    private String name;
    @Field("active")
    private Boolean active; 
}
```

I'm using spring boot with solrCrudRepository and query was

```
@Query(value = "code:?0* name:?0*", filters = "active:?1")
List<SDocument> findAllergenList(String searchKey, Boolean isActive);
```

`org.springframework.data.solr.UncategorizedSolrException: undefined field active; nested exception is org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: undefined field active
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.execute(SolrTemplate.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.count(SolrTemplate.java:154)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.query.AbstractSolrQuery$CollectionExecution.count(AbstractSolrQuery.java:435)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.query.AbstractSolrQuery$CollectionExecution.execute(AbstractSolrQuery.java:415)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.query.AbstractSolrQuery.execute(AbstractSolrQuery.java:149)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:415)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:393)`

Comment: Same Query working in Solr Admin but in springboot not working

Comment: Enable logging of requests in Solr (Admin interface -> Logging, turn it up to `INFO`) and compare the query being sent to Solr from Spring to the query you're typing yourself. They're not going to be identical, as that wouldn't generate an error.

Comment: try using a static value for filters. I mean don't take it as a method argument. hardcode it as true or false and give it a try

Comment: @pvpkiran tried but same error

Comment: @MatsLindh changed logging level to INFO but nothing printed in Logging in Solr Admin . Should i restart solr

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary - try DEBUG and see if you're getting anything at all when searching. Are you sure you're searching against the Solr server you're adjusting the logging options on?